# How to validate signature on the token on SPA using Azure and Django?

Tags: django, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid

I am trying to use Microsoft Outlook mail API in our web application.
Followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial first, but some important thing is skipped in it.

---

[Skipped part]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial#using-the-id-token

> This sample won't do all of the required validations listed in the
>   OpenID spec. Most notably, it won't validate the signature on the
>   token. Currently requesting the signing keys from Azure would require
>   a server-side component, so we'll skip that step for the sake of
>   simplicity. However, production apps should not skip this important
>   step!

In the example code:

```
  // Per Azure docs (and OpenID spec), we MUST validate
  // the ID token before using it. However, full validation
  // of the signature currently requires a server-side component
  // to fetch the public signing keys from Azure. This sample will
  // skip that part (technically violating the OpenID spec) and do
  // minimal validation
```

---

I have a server-side component created with Django, but I'm not sure how to fetch the public signing keys from Azure.

The actual feature I am implementing is sending email via HTML form. I chose to implement this feature on client-side due to several reasons. It's working and I'd like to make authentication secure before deployment.

Just clarify, I followed the tutorial above and use code from this [repo](https://github.com/jasonjoh/javascript-tutorial/tree/outlook-api)  to access Outlook API instead of Microsoft graph. The repo is introduced in the beginning of this tutorial.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the `jwks` or `cert` endpoint in Azure by checking the `well-known` configuration for Azure (something like [this](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration)). You'll be able to find all the active and enabled keys in the [jwks](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys) endpoint in `JSON` format. You can parse those values inside your application and select the required key.